# Mocking and functions split for Php Database Unittesting

Tags: php, database, unit-testing, mocking, dataset

have question about unit tests && and mocking.
I wrote a class  "DataStorage" and usual query looks like:

```
/**
 * @param array $productArray
 */
public function setProductAttributesByProductIds(array $productIdsArray)
{
    $productIdsString = implode(',', $productIdsArray);

    $con = Propel::getConnection();
    $query = $con->prepare(   ... QUERY ..... )
    $query->execute();

    $attributes = $query->fetchAll();

    ___DO SOMETHING WITH DATA___

    return $productArray;
}
```

My suggested approaches:

1. Extract function fetchData(). Then for unittesting just mock it with data.
2. Use PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DataSet_YamlDataSet. Mock the database table with controlled data. Then unittest
3. Do both. Split functions as described in option 1 (clean code approach) AND use DataSets for mocking data.

Question is: Which one do you think is the best approach?

Comment: None of the above. Pass the Propel object in as a dependency and mock that.

Comment: I don't use Propel entities in this class. This code really performance sensitive.

Comment: `$con = Propel::getConnection();` What's this then?